# Degree of a region in a planer graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, plane-geometry

Say i have this planer graph

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckH0l.png)

as we can see it has total 8 edges and 3 regions.

Now degree of a region is the number of edges bordering that region. So what i do not understand is that how we are actually finding it cause according to me

deg(r2) = 7 since there is an edge below (the single one going diagonally) but in the answers its given.

deg(r1)=3

deg(r2)=6

deg(r3)=7

So how do we actually find the number of degrees of a certain region.

Comment: The inner edge in $R_2$ is counted twice.

Comment: @AlexRavsky by inner edge do you mean the bottom one? i thought it might be the twon on top that from the triangle for R1.

Comment: The inner edge I mean is connecting the lowest vertex with the vertex placed in the “interior” of $R_2$. I guess it is counted twice because both its sides are incident to $R_2$.